# What happens if a Pokémon hits multiple evolution criteria at once?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

There's several Pokémon that have branching evolution paths - Slowpoke for example can be evolved into Slowbro by level-up, or into Slowking by trading with King's Rock held.

In most cases, these branches can't conflict, but there's at least one where 3 conditions can be potentially met at once.

Take these three evolution conditions for Eevee:

- Espeon - level up once with a high Happiness value (during the day, or at night for Umbreon)
- Leafeon - level up once nearby the Mossy Rock
- Sylveon - level up once with 2+ Affection and a fairy-type attack.

It's entirely possible for all 3 criteria to be met at the same time (a single Eevee with Charm - Fairy type as of Gen VI -, high affection and friendship, levelled up at the Mossy Rock). Which evolution takes place? Will the game pick randomly, or is logic included to pre-determine the path? Or is it based on which criteria is hit first?

Comment: I intend to research this myself if the answer is not already known.

Comment: Expiermenting is probably the best way to find out. With an emulator, you can carefully craft and easily test/retest hypotheses.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Phew. Man. This isn't super well documented. Here's what I've got:

**Location takes precedence over friendship**:
In the case that your Eevee reaches the correct friendship level while around say, the Mossy Rock, it will always attempt to become Leafeon over Umbreon/Espeon. See [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:Eevee_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Multiple_requirements_met).

**Fairy Move takes precedence over friendship**:
In the case that your Eevee knows a fairy move, it will always attempt to become Sylveon over Umbreon/Espeon... as long as you also have the 2 Affection. Fairy Move without 2 Affection obviously results in no Sylveon. See [here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Talk:Eevee_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29#Evolution_precedence).

The problem is if you hit all criteria. Say you have an Eevee that hits the right friendship level around the Mossy Rock (or the Ice one) and it knows a fairy move (and has 2 Affection). The question is, [what does it turn into](http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1oppeg/x_y_ultimate_guide_to_pok%C3%A9monamie/ccuin26)?

Friendship is the weakest evolution criteria by far (everything trumps friendship). So it probably would be duked out between the Fairy type move and the location. Still, some people say that the process is randomized (this theory is not documented *well*) and some people say that the fairy move/2 Affection will take precedence.

This is just a guess based on looking at all the information I could find, but it looks like the Sylveon evolution has so much going into it that it would be easiest for the game to check this first. See [the comments by Swaggie Mils and Distincct here](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/60943/t1910418-my-eevee-won-evolve-to-sylveon/2.htm). So, **and this is just a guess**, Sylveon *probably* would take precedence over location. We'd need to do a test with multiple Eevees.

**EDIT**: I realized that Swaggie Mils and Distincct say "everything needs to be maxxed out" but I'm pretty sure that this is a safety precaution (to be sure you get a Sylveon). It only needs [two Pokemon Amie hearts and a Fairy move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sylveon), according to Bulbapedia. Fullness is not actually an issue, although I supposed it's best to just max everything out if you're trying to be sure. Still, if you're missing any of the Sylveon evolution criteria, you can't turn into a Sylveon... so I'm **assuming** the game checks for the fairy move, and if there is a fairy move then the affection, else if no fairy move/not enough affection then the location, then the friendship level. But this is a guess and not well documented, based on what I could find. It would still need to be tested.

Comment: @MooingDuck Hmm... well, I'm not sure if contradict is the right word. I can tell you that Location > Friendship and that Fairy/+2 Affection > Friendship, but I can't tell you if Fairy/+2 Affection > Location.  I know that all evolutions trump friendship and I think that it's possible that the Fairy/+2 Affection > Location. But otherwise there doesn't seem to be any contradictions to me, although if you clarify I could make the answer better.

Comment: My bad, I misread

Comment: This random post claims Leafeon has priority: http://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1r2dhb/i_made_a_slight_mistake_when_trying_to_get_a/cdj1m2o

Comment: Yeah, it does, but that is still speculation. And I did say that the last part of my answer is an assumption. It needs to be tested, more or less. You will also find evidence against Leafeon taking priority if you look around enough. People tend to think it's random, but there's not enough proof one way or another.

Comment: If you level up at the moss stone, with 2 Affection and a Fairy move, and high friendship (during the day)...Say it tries to evolve into Leafeon.  If you cancel the evolution (press B), will it then immediately try to evolve into Sylveon?  If you cancel again will it then try to evolve into Espeon?  Or are you forced to go and level up again (and delete your fairy move or intentionally tank your affection to avoid Sylveon)?

Comment: @Doc - No that won't work either, because evolutions can't be 'chained' either. (i.e. if you have a Charmander at level 49, leveling it up once wont get it to Charizard. All that happens on level up is the game checks if it meets a criteria to evolve - if it does it starts the evolution process. Whether it completes or not, it doesn't jump back and do another check-for-evolution afterward.

Comment: I find it amusing that "everything trumps friendship" is the message that Nintendo sends to kids playing this game.

Answer (score 14):

I was very interested in your question, so I did some research.

According to Bulbapedia on [Moss Rock](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moss_Rock), some people have tested that location takes precedence over anything else.

> Even if Eevee has reached other evolutionary conditions, the Moss Rock will still cause it to evolve into Leafeon rather than Espeon, Umbreon, or Sylveon.

So in your scenario, you would get a Leafeon because of your location.

Comment: There is a Mossy Rock in X & Y? I never knew, lol.

Comment: What is the order between the other possible criteria?

Comment: This only answers half the question.  What about Espeon/Umbreon vs Sylveon?

Comment: Sylveon wins out over Umbreon/Espeon

Comment: @Nolonar: It's the huge mossy rock in the forest near Snowbelle you need to cross to complete the game. It's hard to miss, unlike the Ice Rock